# Use the LiveSDK-for-iOS, and access to the one drive for business?

Tags: ios, onedrive

Use the LiveSDK-for-iOS, Is it possible (login, logout, file upload, file download) access to "one drive for business"?

Comment: You did not provide any sufficient information and what have you tried to help you

Answer (score 1):

No, the Live SDK is only for OneDrive consumer.  To access OneDrive for Business, take a look at the Office 365 developer APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx.